# Guacamole with Auth hmac

Tags: authentication, hmac, guacamole

We try to set up no auth on guacamole but we have some troubles.

Down below, steps we have followed :

- Guacamole 0.9.8 installation through docker with containers :

  - guacamole-0.9.8
  - mysql
  - guacd-0.9.8
- Guacamole users creation with guacamole interface.
- Adding the script auth hmac from https://github.com/aiden0z/guacamole-auth-hmac/
- Start file modification on adding properties below :

  set_property "auth-provider" "com.stephensugden.guacamole.net.hmac.HmacAuthenticationProvider"

  set_property "secret-key" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  set_property "timestamp-age-limit" "600000"
- Adding manifest file (guac-manifest.json):

  ```
  {

     "guacamoleVersion" : "0.9.8",



     "name"      : "HMAC Authentication",

     "namespace" : "guac-hmac",



     "authProviders" : [

         "com.stephensugden.guacamole.net.hmac.HmacAuthenticationProvider"

     ]

  }
  ```
- Call url guacamole with signed url and parameters below:

  ```
  id
  timestamp
  guac.hostname
  guac.protocol
  guac.usename
  guac.password
  guac.port
  signature
  ```

This call resulting on white page.

Logs let me things login is correct :

> 15:03:08.026 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG
>   o.g.g.n.b.rest.auth.TokenRESTService - Login was successful for user
>   "0fd88008-26b9-4003-a310-d3408333e871".

However java logs return :

```
22-Oct-2015 15:03:08.027 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMa
ppableContainerException The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a
 response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.stephensugden.guacamole.net.hmac.HmacAuthenticationProvider.getIdentifier()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.glyptodon.guacamole.net.basic.rest.auth.TokenRESTService.createToken(TokenRESTService.java:510)
        at org.glyptodon.guacamole.net.basic.rest.AuthProviderRESTExceptionWrapper.invoke(AuthProviderRESTExceptionWrapper.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can someone tell me more about this error ?